# It looks like Pytest can't rerun tests when running in a container

Tags: python, docker, pytest

I want to run `pytest` inside a container, and I'm finding a different behavior when compared to running `pytest` in the host. Just a simple container, no orchestrators or anything else.

When I run `pytest` at the host level, all tests pass. Some need a couple of `RERUN`, but at the end, they pass.

For example, with a sample of 3 tests, the result of running just `pytest` is `3 passed, 2 rerun in 111.37 seconds`.

Now, if instead of running this in the host, I build an image and run a container, the result is always something along the lines of `1 failed, 2 passed in 73.53 seconds` , or actually any combination of `1 failed 2 passed`, `2 failed 1 passed`, `3 failed`.

Notice how in this case there is no mention to any `rerun` operation?

The image doesn't have anything fancy, it's as simple as copying the requirements, tests and run pytest.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /apptests

COPY requirements requirements
COPY tests tests

RUN pip install -r requirements/tests.txt

CMD ["pytest"]
```

Any ideas about what might be happening? I'm not passing any flag or argument, in both cases (host or docker), it's just a raw `pytest`.

I thought that maybe when a test failed, it was reporting error and the container was exiting (even though I'm not using `pytest -x`), but that's not the case. All tests are run.

Comment: I guess your pipeline create a new container for every run and that will make it forget the earlier run. And BTW if you need to rerun tests to get them working there is something wrong, either the code or the test. You should fix that.

Comment: @KlausD. I agree with that, but that's not really my goal. My goal is to make these tests run in a container, the developers can (and will) fix the rerun. Anyway, the container is run in my host as well for testing purposes, so we can omit the pipeline from the equation here.

Comment: Of cause we can not omit the pipeline. It runs the container in a specific ways with specific settings which are imported to the issue. Pipeline contains are usually throw-away and disposed after run. The default by client creates a new container every time as well. There is no persistence between runs. This can be archived by reusing the container or having a common volume to store the pytest data. Depending on your CI/CD architecture both could be challenging.

Comment: @KlausD. check the updated question. Forget about the pipeline, it's not relevant for this particular issue.

Comment: My previous comment is still valid, especially the middle part.

Comment: Your container will exist after 1 pytest run. If you need to run it multiple times then you have to star the container multiple times. `CMD ["pytest"]` is a one shot.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your `.pytest_cache` in a volume so that each time a new container is started, it has the knowledge of the previous run(s).

For example, using compose.

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: myapp
    command: python -m pytest -v --failed-first
    volumes: [ pytest_cache:/app/.pytest_cache ]

volumes:
  pytest_cache:
```

Comment: no no, guess I'm going to edit the question because it's not clear.

Comment: Did you try? From your questions and comments, I understand that this is your problem. I would give it a shot.

Comment: this makes sense if each test was run in a container, but that's not really the case. All tests are run in the same container before it dies. Anyway, for the sake's of testing, I did, and it's the same result. For example, `===================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 67.49 seconds ======================`

Comment: You need to rerun the container a few times according to your description.

Answer (score 0):

It was quite easy to solve. There was a missing file that needed to be copied to the container which, among other things, had:

```
[tool:pytest]
testpaths=tests
python_files=*.py
addopts = --junitxml=./reports/junit.xml
          --verbose
          --capture=no
          --ignore=setup.py
          --reruns 2                <----------------
          --exitfirst
```

Comment: Is this for the pytest.ini?

Comment: @Jortega in this specific case it was https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#setup-cfg